# How can I put this data into a table?

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, chart

Here is a chart of monthly mean rainfall vs month, and I would like to now get a data table. I would also like to export the table to the drive.
I am not sure how to generate a table, basically I just want the chart displayed in a table format.

```
var hydrobasins = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_3");
var basin = hydrobasins.filter(ee.Filter.eq('HYBAS_ID', 4030050220))

// Calculate Long Term Rainfall Average 

// List of 30 years
var lpaYears = ee.List.sequence(1987, 2016)
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)

// Introducting calendarRange()
var julyImages = chirps
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 7, 'month'))
print(julyImages)

// Introducting flatten()

var nestedList = ee.List([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])
print(nestedList)
print(nestedList.flatten())

// Map over the years and create a monthly totals collection
var monthlyImages = lpaYears.map(function(year) {
  return months.map(function(month) {
    var filtered = chirps
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
    var monthly = filtered.sum()
    return monthly.set({'month': month, 'year': year})
  })
}).flatten()

// We now have 1 image per month for entire long-period duratioon
var monthlyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlyImages)

// We can compute average for each month across all years
var monthlyRainfall = months.map(function(month) {
    var filtered = monthlyCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
    var monthlyMean = filtered.mean()
    return monthlyMean.set('month', month)
})

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyRainfall,
  region: basin,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 5000,
  xProperty: 'month'}).setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'Long Term Monthly Mean Rainfall Over Amu Darya River Basin',
      vAxis: {title: 'Rainfall (mm)'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', gridlines: {count: 12}}
})
print(chart)
```

[Here is the Script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/470cf5e80d7bf9c32346acec61e750fc)

Comment: Normally one displays a chart on the basis of a table of data. It is certainly possible to "reverse-engineer" a chart to extract the underlying data but this is not a GIS issue. It is not clear to me where your source data originates but perhaps people more familiar with google-earth-engine might be able to help.

Comment: Ok I see, I am new to stack exchange, is there a more appropriate place to ask this question than the GIS section?

Answer (score 2):

For displaying your chart you used an imageCollection (monthlyRainfall), a region (basin), a reducer (ee.Reducer.mean()) and a scale (5000). For getting the values used in your chart, as "table", you need to use 'reduceRegion' method with the same parameters as follows:

```
var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec',]

var monthlyRainfallValues = monthlyRainfall.map(function (ele){
  
  var idx = monthlyRainfall.indexOf(ele);
  
  var value = ee.Image(ele)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), basin, scale)
    .get('precipitation');
  
  return [ee.List(months).get(idx), value];
  
});

print(monthlyRainfallValues);
```

Complete code can be obtained [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f8ce1e59d70e37fb1ddd3648875f787).

After running the code on the link, I got the result of following picture. Desired table is inside red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Ahh oh, thank you so much